# Open Profile Pictures List from SharePoint Online MySite

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I need to synchronize SharePoint profile pictures with a local file server directory.
I already successfully synchronize SharePoint lists using a C# application using `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web`, `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List` and friends.

In order to connect to the lists, I use the following URL:

```
https://<tenant_name>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site_name>
```

I select the desired list and the view I would like to access and then it's fairly easy to manipulate the list's contents.

Now, working with the profile pictures, I learned that they are also organized within a SharePoint list, which means that I should be able to use the same mechanisms there. But the profile pictures lay on another SharePoint site called "My Site". And its URL seems to be like this:

```
https://<tenant_name>-my.sharepoint.com
```

The structure is quite different from the "normal" lists. I am not sure which `ClientContext` I should connect to, what's the correct `Web` object and the correct `List` object and I don't see any views there which I could use to load the data into my C# program.

Or does the "standard" `List` approach not work here?

Answer (score 0):

To manipulate profile pictures, you need to use C# CSOM [PeopleManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/jj163361(v=office.15)) object. These Microsoft Learn articles contains some code samples to do this:

1. [Retrieve user profile properties by using the .NET client object
   model in SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-retrieve-user-profile-properties-by-using-the-net-client-object-model-in)
2. [Upload user profile pictures sample SharePoint Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/upload-user-profile-pictures-sample-app-for-sharepoint)